# How to manage small files created due to insertion of stream data into Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am reading Kafka messages using simple Kafka consumer.
Storing the output into HDFS and doing some filtering.

After filtration, I am writing this data into Hive, which causes small orc files into the hive.

Could someone advise me how to handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the number of existing ORC files afterwards by running

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONCATENATE;
or ALTER TABLE tablename PARTITION (field=value) CONCATENATE;
```

To prevent HIVE generating too many ORC files, try with

```
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's tools out there such as Camus and Apache Gobblin which have scripts for the purposes of pulling Kafka data continuously, and having "sweeper / compaction" processes that can be run by schedulers such as Oozie to build larger time partitions

You can also look at Kafka Connect framework with the HDFS plugin by Confluent (you do not need to be running Confluent's Kafka installation to use it). It has support for batching up and large files (I've gotten up to 4GB files per Kafka partition from it) and it will build Hive partitions for you automatically

Or Apache Nifi can be used in between your streams and storage to compress the data before landing on Hadoop

The only other alternative I know of are mapreduce based tools on Github (filecrush is one) or writing your own Hive/Pig/Spark script that reads a location, does very little transformation to it (like calculating a date partition), then writes it out somewhere else. This will cause the smaller blocks to be combined into multiple, and there are hadoop settings in each framework to control how much data should be output per file